# How to get Image real byte size

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I am trying to get Image object real file size though I don't have opportunity to get this image from HDD to read it with File :S 
...OK I write code in this logical direction as

```
ByteArrayOutputStream tmp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    ImageIO.write((BufferedImage) image, "png", tmp);
} catch (IOException ex) {

}
Integer contentLength = tmp.size();
tmp.close();
```

... but the thing is OS shows file size as **65.8KB** but `tmp.size();` in my case returns **63098** :( I am not pretty sure where the ~2KB do skipped; So my question is how to get Image object real file size?

Comment: The difference between the size of the contents of the file, and the size that the OS reports is due to the OS rounding sizes upto file-system page boundaries (for example 4k pages).

Comment: Yes. However, in the code above, I would close() tmp before getting the size.  Maybe not an issue in this case, but with ordinary files or different output streams there may be un-flushed data that would result in size() not returning a correct value.  But in this case, nothing should be buffered for a ByteArrayOutputStream, so the size() should be accurate.

Comment: @brettw Calling `close` on a `ByteArrayOutputStream` has no effect, as [it's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close()) points out.

Comment: That's why I said "But in this case, nothing should be buffered for a ByteArrayOutputStream, so the size() should be accurate".

Comment: I am just wondering... what if the image is not png but code keeps as ImageIO.write((BufferedImage) image, "png", tmp);
 ? Will it effect the size?